# Systemverilog Mailbox and Queue

Tags: system-verilog

I am not able to understand, Why we prefer Mailbox over Queue for inter process communication (eg: communication between Driver and Scoreboard)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mailbox is a built-in class around a queue that uses semaphores to control access to the ends of a queue. A mailbox only has FIFO element ordering whereas you can access the head, tail, or middle elements of a queue.

You typically use a mailbox when there are multiple threads reading and writing data and you need the atomic test-and-set operation of semaphore to know when the mailbox is full or empty. If you have only one process reading and writing to a queue, there is no need to use a mailbox. However if there are more than one thread, a mailbox is a convenient class to use.

In the UVM, we use a TLM FIFO which is another wrapper around a mailbox. TLM connections provide an isolating interface so you don't have to know what is on the other side of your port. See https://verificationacademy.com/sessions/how-tlm-works